# how to import selenium WebElement in python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to import selenium `WebElement` since I need to check if a function returns a `WebElement` or not

I have googled but only find how to import selenium, such as `from selenium import webdriver`, I already have that working. The error part is the type checking line such as:

```
if isinstance(var, WebElement):
    #do something
else:
    #do nothing
```

so the question is what is the class path for selenium's `WebElement`? for example `from selenium.common import WebElement` (already tried this and not working)

Comment: `from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement` ?

Comment: No problem! Just so you know, I have selenium installed in PyCharm and simply typed `WebElement` and then ALT+ENTER to find the path (auto-import).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

in case someone did not see the answer, its in the comment:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
```

i'm adding this answer to close this question, thanks for the help